# putchar() output is a question mark instead entered input stream

Tags: c, do-while, eof, getchar, putchar

I'm trying to output an input stream with alphabet characters in a do-while loop and when
the user does EOF(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>) the loop stops and the output should be the input stream, but the output is just a question mark in a box... What is wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char c;

    do{
        c = getchar();
    } while (c != EOF);

    printf("Output:\n");
    putchar(c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char c` provides storage for exactly one character. It does not concatenate all of the characters returned by `getchar()` in the loop. After the loop, it has the last character that `getchar()` returned, which is the EOF.

Comment: c value is equal to the EOF state.So you are basically "trying to display EOF".

Comment: Put `putchar(c)` inside the loop.

Comment: Also, you need to declare `int c;`

Answer (score 1):

`getchar` returns an `int`, so you should make your char an int. Also, if you get an `EOF` and you overwrite `c`, then you'll be calling `putchar(EOF)` after the loop, which isn't a printable character. (EOF is `-1` which gets casted to `char` which becomes `\xff`). If you want the input stream, then you have to store the input stream:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define INPSIZE 2000

int main() {
    char inp[INPSIZE + 1];
    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        int c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF) {
            break;
        }
        inp[i++] = c;
        // don't overflow
        if (i >= INPSIZE) {
            break;
        }
    }
    // we need terminating nullbyte
    inp[i] = '\x00';
    puts("Output:");
    puts(inp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable c ***always*** holds the EOF state value when you exit your loop. You could try to save the input in an array, or the easier way, you could display each character in your loop.

*Storing in array:*

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 500

int main (void)
{
  char c;
  char arr[SIZE];
  size_t i = 0U;

 while ((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
      if (i<SIZE-1) /* Consider you want your output as a string,save space for NULL */
      {
          arr[i++]=c;
      }
      else
      {
          puts("buffer full");
          break;
      }
    }
  
  arr[i]='\0';
  

  printf ("Output: %s\n",arr);
  
  return 0;
}
```

*Display each character*:

```
#include <stdio.h>    

int main (void)
{
  char c;
  
  while ((c=getchar())!=EOF)
  {
      putchar(c);
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get something done for how I wanted to write the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>    


    int main (void){
    int c;
    char c_arr[500];
    size_t i = 0U;
    
    do{
    
    c_arr[i++] = c = getchar();
    
      }while(c!= EOF);
    
    c_arr[i] = '\0';
    i-=1;
    
    printf("Output:\n");
    
    for(size_t a = 0U ; a < i; a++){
    putchar(c_arr[a]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is that code okay or are there any optimizations possible  ?

And another question is about size_t, is it better to use than a normal int for arrays or for-loops like I did in my for-loop or does it not matter ?

Thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Comment: a) not really optimization ... but you can improve the consistency of your indentation and the use of whitespace, check if you're not writing more than 500 chars into the array; b) `int` vs `size_t` shouldn't matter for your example, though `size_t` (or `unsigned`) is more natural because you will never have negative indexes.

Comment: i don't really understand what you mean in answer a)